# ack executed through vim

Tags: vim, ack

I am trying to execute ack from vim. But for some reason vim decides to stop after executing ack. How can I stop vim from stopping?

(on some systems what I call ack is called ack-grep)

What I am doing in vim:

```
:!ack something
```

what happens is this:

```
$vim myfile.myextension

somefile.someext
356:              : this line contains something and somewhat

[1]+  Stopped                 vim chatconfig.js
```

When I run `fg` it says this:

```
vim myfile.myextension

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

And when I press enter it returns to vim.

What I expect to happen is this:

```
$vim myfile.myextension

somefile.someext
356:              : this line contains something and somewhat

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

so without the fg thing.

I have a workaround, by piping ack to something silly:

```
:!ack something | grep -v "asdasdasd"
```

But I would like to just know the trick, which is automatically happening when piping to grep.

Vim7.4, Ubuntu 15.10, ack 2.14

Comment: Try `:!ack --flush something`.  BTW, `ack` works fine from `vim` for me.  ack 2.14, vim 7.4,  debian sid.  Also BTW did you read the section in the `ack` man page about `Vim integration`?

Comment: @cas, Thanks, but the --flush option did not help. Thanks for pointing out vim integration, that looks like a workable situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had this hack in my vimrc:

```
set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

to get bash aliases to work in vim. This caused the described behaviour. By piping ack to another process ack will be runned non-interactive.

Solution, delete the hack.